# Table of Dynamic@If in ClickPane unevaluated

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic

I want to display a graph with additional information and further information to appear in popups. Based on prior discussions here, I am trying to use `ClickPane` but I am running into the problem that the `Dynamic@If` statements necessary must be in `Table`s and remain unevaluated.

For example, the code

```
step = 2 Pi/6;
Graphics[{
  Table[
   {Blue, Tooltip[Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2], ToString@x]}
   , {x, step, 2 Pi, step}]
  }]
```

works fine, but if I try the code

```
step = 2 Pi/6;
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, ClickPane[
  Graphics[{
    Table[
     Dynamic@If[pt \[Element] Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2],
       {Red, Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2], White, 
        Text[ToString@x, {Cos[x], Sin[x]}]}
       , {Blue, Tooltip[Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2], ToString@x]}]
     , {x, step, 2 Pi, step}]
    }]
  , (pt = #) &]]
```

then I get the error that If is not a graphics primitive.

Any ideas?

Per Kuba's suggestion, the code

`step = 2 Pi/6;
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, ClickPane[
  Graphics[{
    Table[With[{x = x1},
      Dynamic@If[pt \[Element] Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2],
        {Red, Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2], White, 
         Text[ToString@x, {Cos[x], Sin[x]}]}
        , {Blue, Tooltip[Disk[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, .2], ToString@x]}]]
     , {x1, step, 2 Pi, step}]
    }]
  , (pt = #) &]]`

works, but still unclear to me why.

Comment: You need `Table[With[{x=x` as `Dynamic` is `HoldAll`.

Comment: @Kuba, could you please explain?

Comment: Take a look at the answer in topic I've linked